# User defined filter for linq

Tags: .net, linq, filter

I have form with user defined filters ( combobox with column names, combobox with filter types and textbox with value).

How can I dynamicly add user defined filter into LINQ query?

Typical query looks like:

```
var qProducts = from p in db.Products
    where p.IsArchived == false
    order by p.ProductName select p;
```

I'm using LINQ (IQuerable Toolkit) for access data in SQL CE database.

Comment: This might help: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/5edb3dd0-c778-47e2-b89d-a9c90a0bd1bc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to look at [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) from the [VS2008 Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpsamples). Then you could do something like:

```
var qProducts = db.Products
                  .Where( "IsArchived = {0}", archiveFilterValue )
                  .OrderBy( sortColumn + " " + sortDirection );
```

Answer (score -1):

you can add each filter dynamically if it's needed, e.g.:

```
if (txtFilter1.Text!="") qProducts=qProducts.Where(s=>s.Name==txtFilter1.Text);
if (txtFilter2.Text!="") qProducts=qProducts.Where(s=>s.Field==txtFilter2.Text);
if (cboCombo1.SelectedValue!=0) qProducts=qProducts.Where(s=>s.price...
```

and so on

Comment: I want to do it dynamicly with reuse on every filterable table.
Writing "if" for every column in database is not practical.