# LINQ Dynamic Where - string parameter missing

Tags: c#, linq

I am sure this is something really simple, but I am going bonkers trying to figure out why.

I have the following code:

```
string condition = string.Format("{0}.Contains({1})", column, value);

var query = DataContext.MyTable.Where(condition);
```

The strange thing that I am getting is an error saying:

```
Argument cannot convert from string to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<Context.MyTable, bool>>'
```

I thought that you could pass in a string to the where clause without a problem such as indicated in this post:

[Dynamic WHERE clause in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848415/linq-dynamic-where-clause/848435#848435)

Any thoughts on what I am missing? Perhaps an invalid namespace (I have System.Linq)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to:

1. Download [dynamic query](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpsamples) with the C# samples.
2. Reference it in your project.
3. Add `using System.Linq.Dynamic`
4. Follow the format specified in the documentation for that library.

Comment: Thank you, I am giving you accepted answer only because you answered first and I found the information before the other person posted and I did not see his post until after I got it to work. This worked like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

That answer has a link to a library that you need to download.

Comment: Thanks I did not see that in there before. +1 for the info though. Thanks!