# How to make a dynamic where clause: linq to sql

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq-to-sql

I have the following linq query:

```
        Dim q = From definition In definitionList _
            Where definition.ValueDefName.Contains(criteria) _
            Select definition.ValueDefName, definition.ValueDefDesc, definition.DateCreated, _
            definition.StrategicInitiative, definition.ValueWikiURL, definition.ValueDefinitionStatusID, _
            definition.Aliaslist
```

I have already looked into this answer: [Dynamic WHERE clause in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848415/linq-dynamic-where-clause)

Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me using .net 4.0. When I attempt to pass the criteria string in it ask for a predicate. The end goal is to add any of these:

1. definition.ValueDefname.Contains(criteria)
2. definition.ValueDefDesc.Contains(criteria)
3. definition.Aliaslist.Contains(Criteria)
4. definition.StrategicInitiative.Contains(Criteria)

to be passed into the query depending on what checkboxes the user has selected. How can I create a dynamic where clause in linq to sql? Is there new syntax for passing in a where clause as a string?

Answer (score 1):

For LINQ to SQL, the Dynamic LINQ approach would be the only option to pass a string as the Where clause.  Alternatively, the Where clause takes an Expression, and you can dynamically build an expression using this approach:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx

I did this using Entity Framework, I believe this works with LINQ to SQL too.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure this answers your need, but we use lambda expression functions passed into our search methods:

In our repository class:

```
public override IEnumerable<KeyCode> FindAll(Expression<Func<KeyCode, bool>> filter)
{
    return GetAll().AsQueryable().Where(filter);
}
```

And in some other location

```
KeyCodeRepository keycodeRepository = new KeyCodeRepository(unitOfWork);
IEnumerable<KeyCode> keyCodes = keycodeRepository
    .FindAll(k => k.FlowStatus.Value == (int)FlowStatusType.Active 
                                    && k.AppSystem.Id == appSystemId);
```

The expression

```
k.FlowStatus.Value == (int)FlowStatusType.Active && k.AppSystem.Id == appSystemId
```

is passed in as an expression to the Where clause in the FindAll method.  This allows us to dynamically determine our filters anytime we call FindAll();

Comment: I accidentally click the down arrow. I'm unable to undo. Sorry

Comment: Undid that down arrow for ya :)