# Trying to execute a WHERE IN: Invalid 'where' condition. An entity member is invoking an invalid property or method

Tags: linq, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm trying to get a list of cases whose AccountID is found in a previous list.

The error occurs on the last line of the following:

```
// Gets the list of permissions for the current contact
var perms = ServiceContext.GetCaseAccessByContact(Contact).Cast<Adx_caseaccess>();

// Get the list of account IDs from the permissions list
var customerIDs = perms.Select(p => p.adx_accountid).Distinct();

// Get the list of cases that belong to any account whose ID is in the `customerID` list
var openCases = (from c in ServiceContext.IncidentSet where customerIDs.Contains(c.AccountId) select c).ToList();
```

I'm not sure what the "invalid property" is the error is talking about. The code compiles, I just get the error at runtime.

Comment: What was that `... from c in XrmContext.IncidentSet where ...` meant to do?

Comment: Get the list of cases whose AccountID appears in customerIDs, updated question to clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the [CRM Linq Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328328.aspx#limitations). It doesn't support all of the available options that the Linq-to-objects provider offers. In this case, the CRM does not support the `Enumerable.Contains()` method.

> **where**:
>   The left side of the clause must be an attribute name and the
>   right side of the clause must be a value. You cannot set the left side
>   to a constant. Both the sides of the clause cannot be constants.
>   Supports the **String** functions **Contains**, **StartsWith**, **EndsWith**, and
>   **Equals**.

You can work around this in one of two ways:

1. Rework your query to use a more natural join.
2. If a join is not possible, you can use Dynamic Linq to generate a list of `OR` clauses on each item in `customerIDs`. This would function similarly to `Enumerable.Contains`.

See my answer or the accepted answer to the question ["How to get all the birthdays of today?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10146065/684271) for two separate ways to accomplish this.

Comment: When trying this, I get this error: 

An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1' occurred in Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll but was not handled in user code.

Additional information: Generic SQL error.