# LINQ is it possible to add where clauses dynamically

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, where-clause

I want to search my db with different keys. According to the input, there may be 1 key to 10 keys. Is there a way to add OR/AND clauses to my Linq query dynamically?

```
 keys[k] // I have my keys in this array 
 var feedList = (from feed in ctx.Feed
                 where feed.content.contains(keys[0]) 
                       && feed.content.contains(keys[1])
                       && ... // continues with the keys.length
                 select new {
                    FeedId = feed.DuyuruId,
                    FeedTitle = feed.FeedTitle,
                    FeedContent = feed.FeedContents,
                    FeedAuthor = user.UserName + " " +User.UserSurname
 }
```

Comment: might want to check out; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848415/linq-dynamic-where-clause?rq=1

Comment: I just made up the 10 keys, there should not be any restriction.

Comment: link shared by @SomeMiscGuy is what you need. I have created entire linq query and it works like charm. It gels well with existing `IEnumerable` and `IQueryable` extensions.

Comment: Dynamic LINQ can be a useful solution, but unnecessary in this example.  DLINQ will incur a significant amount of overhead if you use it excessively because it relies on reflection behind the scenes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could try an [**`.All`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx) clause to check all the keys:

```
where keys.All(key => feed.content.contains(key))
```

Answer (score 7):

For AND clauses it is simple:

```
var feedList = from feed in ctx.Feed;
foreach(var key in keys){
    feedList = feedList.Where(x=> content.contains(key));
}
var resultQuery = feedList.Select(x=> new {....});
```

For OR you will need to use `Expressions` or try [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) and its predicates :

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<TypeOfYourEntity>();
foreach(var key in keys){
    predicate = predicate.Or(x=> content.contains(key));
}
var resultQuery = ctx.Feed.Where(predicate).Select(x=> new {....});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the extension methods of LINQ

```
ctx.Feed.Where(f => {  
//Your logic here
if(something != null){
      return f.Property == something
  } 
}).Select( new { FeedId = feed.DuyuruId,
                    FeedTitle = feed.FeedTitle,
                    FeedContent = feed.FeedContents,
                    FeedAuthor = user.UserName + " " +User.UserSurname })
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this. Remember it may casue some overhead

```
 var students = ctx.Students;

 if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SearchParams.Name))
      students = from s in students where s.Name.StartsWith(SearchParams.Name)

 if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SearchParams.Surname))
      students = from s in students where s.Surname.StartsWith(SearchParams.Surname)
```

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to provide an example of how @mellamokb's answer worked for my scenario to possibly help out anyone needing a fairly dynamic `linq` query.

In my example I have simply made an extension of the `datatable` class so I can check if a row of data exists as it stands in the database so no `SQL` primary key exceptions are thrown.

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="DT"></param>
/// <param name="ColumnNames">Columns to check in affected table.</param>
/// <param name="ItemtoChecks">Values to check in affected column.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static bool TableContains(this DataTable DT, string[] ColumnNames, object[] ItemtoChecks)
{
  var result = from row in DT.AsEnumerable()
               where ColumnNames.All(
               r => row.Field<object>(r).ToString() == Convert.ToString(
                 ItemtoChecks[ColumnNames.ToList()
                 .FindIndex(p => p.Equals(r, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))]))
               select row;                   
  return (result.Count() > 0);
}
```

This method allows you to add as many column names as you require to a `string[]` along with the corresponding values to check in a separate `object[]`. The query checks against the `datatable` and if it finds a match the method returns `true` and if not it returns `false`.