# Using an expression parser in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, math, expression

i am not sure if this is a typical stackoverflow question, but i am working on an application where i should constantly examine some conditions (for example if a certain variable's value is over a threshold). Conditions can be changed at any time and preferably from outside the code.

People suggested i should be using expression parsers, but i still don't understand what advantage do they provide me over basic mathematical operations provided by .NET.

Do you recommend a good .NET expression parser?

Comment: What can change? Your threshold? or the entire form of the condition?

Comment: more likely, the entire form of the condition.

Comment: can't you think of anything more simple? An expression parser could work OK, but it seems a little too much.. can you give an example?

Comment: Also: which syntax would you like to use? are you referring to variables (local, global, inside the current class...) too?

Comment: an example of the logic i should be doing is that if an error occurred i should send an email to report it, if the error occurred again i should not re-report till at least 30 mins.. if the same error message occurred more than 100 times then send SMS....and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need Dynamic LINQ. You can pass the conditions as strings.

Here is a blog post about that by ScottGu: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

I found this by a similar question: [Dynamic WHERE clause in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848415/linq-dynamic-where-clause)

Comment: im going to ask you a dumb question since im a newbie to .NET, isn't LINQ related to DB querying? in my case the data is stored in the memory ( code variables).

Comment: No, LINQ is for querying all kinds of collections (enumerables). It doesn't matter if it is in DB or in memory.

Answer (score 0):

An expression parser would offer more flexibility. Your expressions could be written as formulars in strings and they could be application data instead of harcoded classes/methods/whatever.

You could do things like:

```
// Assign an action to an expression given as a string
ExpressionObserver.Add("(a+b+c)/2 > x-y", () => { DoSomething(); });
```

Or:

```
// Replace the old expression by something written by the user in the UI
someExpressionActionAssignment.Expression = MyLineEdit1.Text;
```

But I do not know if the added complexity of all this really pays off in your case. If you only have a few simple expressions then it's probably overkill.