# Dynamically specifying lambda function parameters

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, lambda

Suppose I have the following line of code:

```
context.Load(itemCollection, item => item.Include(i => i["Title"], i => i["Name"]));
```

Is there any way I can dynamically specify the parameters to the `item.Include()` function instead of hard-coding them as above?

I would ideally like to allow users to select properties they want to retrieve of an object such as `Title`, `Name`, `Description`, etc.

FYI, here is the `ClientContext.Load` function. This function is coming from `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll`

```
public void Load<T>(T clientObject, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] retrievals) where T : ClientObject
{
  if ((object) clientObject == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("clientObject");
  ClientAction.CheckActionParameterInContext(this, (object) clientObject);
  DataRetrieval.Load<T>(clientObject, retrievals);
}
```

Comment: yes, I make functions like this for MS CRM libraries all the time.  You want to investigate `public void MyMethod<t>(Func<Expression<t,object>> expression) where t : ` extending the type you want in the expression.  Anyway, search on Func for more examples

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the necessary setup to test it, but will something like this work?

```
String[] keys = ...;
context.Load(   itemCollection
              , item => item
                        .Include(keys
                        .Select(key => { i => i[key] })
                        .ToArray()
            );
```

Comment: No. We don't know how many keys (properties) the user wants to retrieve.

Comment: What are the signatures of the context.Load() and item.Include() functions?

Comment: Updated my question with the info you requested.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848415/linq-dynamic-where-clause).
I had a similar problem with creating dynamic where clauses, and this is how I got around it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following syntaxt (works in JavaScript, but haven't tested it in C#):

```
context.load(this.list, 'Include(Title, Name)');
```

`'Include(Title, Name)'` is a string and is easier to generate based on user input.

`this.list` *refers to a sharepoint list that is loaded before.*