# How to use a dynamic string to filter a field X with a string?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Something like this:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static IQueryable<MovieList> FilterEntityCollection(this IQueryable<MovieList> movies, IEnumerable<Foo.Models.FilterCriteria> filters)
    {
        foreach (var filter in filters)
        {
            // Apply the filter to the collection.
            movies= movies.Where(x => x.filter.FieldName == filter.expr);
                                    //x."MovieTitle"       == "Jaws" 
        }

        return movies;
    }
}
```

Can something like this be done in C#?

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ - dynamic WHERE clause?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848415/linq-dynamic-where-clause)

Comment: You can use reflection for the kind of flexibility you are looking for.
Since this is expensive, I guess the question is what are you using for to persist this movies? Does it have any query capabilities at all?

Comment: Data is saved in a MSSQL database.

Comment: Then the link in the first comment should help. That query will be taking place in the SQL engine, rather than in memory as I assumed given you code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx)

Sort of like:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<MovieList>();

foreach (var filter in filters)
{
    string filter1 = filter;
    predicate = predicate.And(a => a.filter.FieldName == filter1);
}
return movies.AsExpandable().Where(predicate);
```

LinqKit predicate builder

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace LinqKit
{
    public static class PredicateBuilder
    {
        public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1, Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2);
        public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> False<T>();
        public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1, Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2);
        public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> True<T>();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's about getting string values into expressions.