# Build Predicate based on Filter values passed in

Tags: c#, predicate

I would like to filter my List for Reporting purposes but i would like to make it as dynamic as possible so that the user can Filter on 1 or more columns.

The idea i have is to create a Dictionary and then pass that to a method that will filter out the relevant records but i am now stuck as to how i would do the "Dynamic" part.

This is how my current code looks so far but it is not working.

```
filters = {CourseId,2},{CourseDescription,Maths}

public IQueryable<Course> Filter(Dictionary<string,string> filters)
{
    var a = from s in context.Courses
                  select s;
    foreach (var filter in filters)
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.Value))
        {
            a = a.Where(s => s./*filter.Key*/.ToUpper().Contains(/*filter.value*/.ToUpper()));
        }
    }
}
```

Please can someone assist and point me into the correct direction so that i can get this working.

Thank you.

Comment: Your `filters` definition does not match `Dictionary<string, string>` declaration. You don't have any `string` in your code...

Comment: Perhaps this question is related to what you are trying to do?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848415/linq-dynamic-where-clause

Comment: This one written by someone in Microsoft can build IQueryable by parameters of strings, and it is in fact in the Samples along with Visual Studio, namely Dynamic.cs.http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your link Lei Yang. 
This seems to be the answer for my question :
[http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I have just recently used http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx to dynamically build a predicate to use with Entity Framework, based on criteria that is received.  Works quite well.