# Using variables to build a LinQ query?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I don't think is possible but wanted to ask to make sure. I am currently debugging some software someone else wrote and its a bit unfinished.

One part of the software is a search function which searches by different fields in the database and the person who wrote the software wrote a great big case statement with 21 cases in it 1 for each field the user may want to search by.

Is it possible to reduce this down using a case statement within the Linq or a variable I can set with a case statement before the Linq statement?

Example of 1 of the Linq queries: (Only the Where is changing in each query)

```
var list = (from data in dc.MemberDetails
    where data.JoinDate.ToString() == searchField
    select new
        {
            data.MemberID,
            data.FirstName,
            data.Surname,
            data.Street,
            data.City,
            data.County,
            data.Postcode,
            data.MembershipCategory,
            data.Paid,
            data.ToPay
        }
).ToList();
```

Update / Edit:

This is what comes before the case statement:

```
string searchField = txt1stSearchTerm.Text;
string searchColumn = cmbFirstColumn.Text;
switch (cmbFirstColumn.SelectedIndex + 1)
{
```

The cases are then done by the index of the combo box which holds the list of field names.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ - dynamic WHERE clause?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848415/linq-dynamic-where-clause)

Comment: @GSerg I don't think this is a duplicate question since the criteria are known at compile time, just not which ones are applicable at a given situation. There is nothing to gain by doing it `.Where("data.JoinDate == " + searchField)` over `.Where(x => x.JoinDate == searchField)`

Comment: @Maarten The users selects which fields to search by (out of 21 available fields). That is exactly the problem described in the linked question. Doing `Where`s manually would require a 21-bullet `switch`, which is what the OP currently has, as I understand.

Comment: I will take a look at the linked answer, I am a bit out of my depth with this project, I am a web developer not a C# developer so I am learning as I go here. Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 1):

Given that `where` takes a predicate, you can pass any method or function which takes `MemberDetail` as a parameter and returns a boolean, then migrate the switch statement inside.

```
private bool IsMatch(MemberDetail detail)
{
    // The comparison goes here.
}

var list = (from data in dc.MemberDetails
    where data => this.IsMatch(data)
    select new
    {
        data.MemberID,
        data.FirstName,
        data.Surname,
        data.Street,
        data.City,
        data.County,
        data.Postcode,
        data.MembershipCategory,
        data.Paid,
        data.ToPay
    }
).ToList();
```

Note that:

- You may look for a more object-oriented way to do the comparison, rather than using a huge switch block.
- An anonymous type with ten properties that you use in your `select` is kinda weird. Can't you return an instance of `MemberDetail`? Or an instance of its base class?

Comment: This won't work with Entity Framework.. although, not specified, the SQL tag suggests to me that is what he's using

Comment: @MartinBooth: good point, I've forgotten about this one. I'll remove my answer if it appears to be the author's case.

Answer (score 1):

How are the different where statements handled, are they mutually excluside or do they all limit the query somehow?

Here is how you can have one or more filters for a same query and materialized after all filters have been applied.

```
var query = (from data in dc.MemberDetails
             select ....);

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchField))
    query = query.Where(pr => pr.JoinDate.ToString() == searchField);

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(otherField))
    query = query.Where(....);

return query.ToList();
```