# Dynamic Or Clause Linq

Tags: c#, linq, where-clause, conditional-statements, dynamic-linq

Today we currently have a statement like this:

```
var Query = (from dp in db.Patients
            select dp);

var UserID = User.Identity.GetUserId();

if (User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
{
    Query = Query.Where(x => x.AdministratorID == UserID);
}
if (User.IsInRole("Counselor"))
{
    Query = Query.Where(x => x.CounselorID == UserID);
}
if (User.IsInRole("Physician"))
{
    Query = Query.Where(x => x.PhysicianID == UserID);
}
```

The problem is we have Users that can have multiple roles. If a User is both an Counselor and Physician we want the system to pull back all patients where CounselorID == UserID or PhysicianID == UserID.

**How can this be accomplished dynamically if we don't know what role a user will have when the page is loaded?**

The current .Where clause just uses an **AND** statement we need an **OR** statment.

Ideally there would be a solution like this:

```
if (User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
{
     Query = Query.Where(x => x.AdministratorID == UserID);
}
if (User.IsInRole("Counselor"))
{
     Query = Query.WhereOr(x => x.CounselorID == UserID);
}
if (User.IsInRole("Physician"))
{
     Query = Query.WhereOr(x => x.PhysicianID == UserID);
}
```

Comment: you can use [DynamicLinq](http://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/) or use [Expression class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.linq.expressions.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) and build your custom predicate

Comment: Can the user have a `CounselorID == UserID` without having the role Counselor?

Comment: possibly duplicate [LINQ - dynamic WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848415/linq-dynamic-where-clause?rq=1)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can build a predicate incrementally.

```
Func<Pantient, bool> predicate = p => false;

if (User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
{
    var oldPredicate = predicate;
    predicate = p => oldPredicate(p) || p.AdministratorID == UserID;
}

if (User.IsInRole("Counselor"))
{
    var oldPredicate = predicate;
    predicate = p => oldPredicate(p) || p.CounselorID == UserID;
}


var query = db.Patients.Where(predicate);
```

Comment: Thanks @dcastro, this helped lead me to http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Comment: I'm confused on where the variable `x` is coming from? It seems like the predicate building would go in a separate method, but I'm having a hard time figuring out the appropriate method signature.

Comment: @TheMuffinMan oops, x was supposed to be p. Fixed now

Comment: @dcastro that makes a lot more sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

would this work?

```
var query = Patients.Where(
    x => (User.IsInRole("Administrator") && x.AdministratorID == UserID)
      || (User.IsInRole("Counselor") && x.CounselorID == UserID)
      || (User.IsInRole("Physician") && x.PhysicianID == UserID)
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone else is looking a different solution i found [linqkit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit)
very usefull and easy to use. So in your example the solution would be something like this:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<Patients>(true);

if (User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
{
     predicate = predicate.Or(x => x.AdministratorID == UserID);
}

if (User.IsInRole("Counselor"))
{
     predicate  = predicate.Or(x => x.CounselorID == UserID);
}

if (User.IsInRole("Physician"))
{
     predicate  = predicate.Or(x => x.PhysicianID == UserID);
}

query = query.Where(predicate)
```