# Query with dynamic where clause (concatenated array elements)

Tags: vb.net, linq, dynamic-linq

I have a dynamic array where the elements should filter elements (where clause) in a linq query.

I use the `System.Linq.Dynamic` Library mentioned in [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848415/linq-dynamic-where-clause) top answer. If I run:

```
Dim query = From element In dtImitate.Where("Team = ""Avangers"" Or Team = ""Asgard""")
```

the query is working. But if I collect the array elements and put them into a string like this:

```
Public Shared Function CreateDynString(ByRef arr As String()) As String
 Dim a As New StringBuilder
        a.Append("""")
        For Each element In arr
            a.Append("Team = ").Append("""""").Append(element).Append("""""").Append(" or ")
        Next

        Dim b As Integer = a.Length - 4
        a.Remove(b, 4)
        a.Append("""")
        Return a.ToString
End Function
```

and run the query:

```
Dim s As String = DynamicStringBuilder.CreateDynString(teamsArray).ToString
Dim query = From element In dtImitate.Where(s)
```

Nothing happens. My DGV stays empty. Can anyone help me get this query to work and can tell me, why it is not working. If I print `s` it is `"Team = ""Avangers"" Or Team = ""Asgard"""`. I dont know why it is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're testing for a property to be in an array, you can use the `Contains` extension method on `IEnumerable`, which is probably preferable to building a string. Try this:

```
Dim query = From element In dtImitate.Where(function (el) teamsArray.Contains(el.Team))
```