# Using DateDiff with Linq.Dynamic library for fetching today records

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am trying to fetch all records added today using DateDiff SQL syntax via Linq expression in MVC 5 / Entity Framework 6 application. DateDiff function throw runtime error

Actually i want to the following linq WHERE clause to parse with linq dynamics

```
.Where(p => DbFunctions.DiffDays(p.added_date, DateTime.Now) == 0)
```

in order to fetch today added records. Sample code that i am using shown below

```
var _list = new vsk_error_log();
using (var entities = new vskdbEntities())
{
   _list = entities.vsk_error_log
  //.Where("DateDiff(DAY,added_date,getdate())=0")
  .Where(p => DbFunctions.DiffDays(p.added_date, DateTime.Now) == 0)
  .ToList();
}
return _list;
```

Regarding Linq.Dynamic Expressions - how to write where clause

[Dynamic WHERE clause in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848415/linq-dynamic-where-clause)

Comment: No property or field 'DAY' exists in type 'vsk_error_log'...

Comment: Why you are running SQL code on .NET objects?

Comment: you should close the ) 
`"DateDiff(DAY,added_date,getdate())=0"`

Comment: DAY is not property but constant parameter for DateDiff function. It can be dy or wk for week etc

Comment: @YairNevet i am using linq.dynamics to dynamically generate select / where / orderby clause

Comment: @Javad_Amiry i added ) but still same error

Comment: Do you have a field called `DAY`?

Comment: @YairNevet added_date is field, DAY is filtering expression of DateDiff

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use `DbFunctions`

```
.Where(p => DbFunctions.DiffDays(p.AddedDate, DateTime.Now) == 0)
```

**Edit:**

If you want to invoke this dynamically, you'll need to modify code for the Dynamic LINQ.

1. Download the [sample project containing DynamicLibrary.cs](http://www.scottgu.com/blogposts/dynquery/dynamiclinqcsharp.zip). The file is located under App_Code folder.
2. Find the static definition for `predefinedTypes` and add `typeof(DbFunctions)` at the very end.

Now you will be able to do this:

```
.Where("DbFunctions.DiffDays(AddedDate, DateTime.Now) = 0")
```

And it will be translated to this SQL:

```
WHERE 0 = (DATEDIFF (day, [Extent1].[AddedDate], SysDateTime()))
```

Comment: i want to use it in linq.Dynamic expression like mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848415/linq-dynamic-where-clause

Comment: I tried but DiffDays is not recognized as proper method.

Comment: Are you sure you were referencing the file you downloaded instead of the nuget package? I've tested the above and it is working fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

flindeberg is correct when he say that System.Linq.Dynamic parses the expression that you give as C#, not SQL.

However, Entity Framework defines the class "DbFunctions" that allows you call sql functions as part of your Linq queries.

DbFunctions.DiffDays is the method that you are looking for. With this, you also don't need to be using System.Linq.Dynamic.

Your code would look something like this, I think:

```
     var _list = new vsk_error_log();
     using ( var entities = new vskdbEntities() )
     {
        _list = entities.vsk_error_log
          .Where( entry => DbFunctions.DiffDays( entry.added_date, DateTime.UtcNow ) == 0 )
          .ToList();
     }
     return _list;
```

If you want to use this function with System.Linq.Dynamic, it would look something like this:

```
     var _list = new vsk_error_log();
     using ( var entities = new vskdbEntities() )
     {
        _list = entities.vsk_error_log
          .Where( "DbFunctions.DiffDays( added_date, DateTime.UtcNow ) == 0" )
          .ToList();
     }
     return _list;
```

HOWEVER! System.Linq.Dynamic will not recognize the class DbFunctions, and as such, this will not work out of the box. However, we can "patch" this functionality in using a bit of reflection, although it can be a bit ugly:

```
     var type = typeof( DynamicQueryable ).Assembly.GetType( "System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser" );

     FieldInfo field = type.GetField( "predefinedTypes", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic );

     Type[] predefinedTypes = (Type[])field.GetValue( null );

     Array.Resize( ref predefinedTypes, predefinedTypes.Length + 1 );
     predefinedTypes[ predefinedTypes.Length - 1 ] = typeof( DbFunctions );

     field.SetValue( null, predefinedTypes );
```

By running this code, System.Linq.Dynamic will now recognize DbFunctions as a type that can be used in the parsed C# expressions.

Comment: yes that what i want. same DiffDays equivalent function i needed to use with linq dynamic expression instead of direct linq.

Comment: I see, if you need to use dynamic linq with DbFunction you need to use a bit of a workaround due to the way System.Linq.Dynamic is implemented. I'll post a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is never executed in the database, the "issue" is that `Linq.Dynamic` tries to parse it as `C#` code, where it fails. As far as I know it is not possible to call `SQL` with dynamic linq.

I believe you are looking for is using raw `SQL`, not `.NET` code which `Linq.Dynamic` is, [this page at MSDN will give you more information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx) about using raw `SQL`.

Comment: yes but alternatively how to execute this DbFunctions.DiffDays(p.added_date, DateTime.Now) on dynamics.

Comment: @irfanmcsd Your where does not need to be dynamic. You know that you can mix dynamic and non-dynamic linq? Is there a reason you are using dynamic linq?

Comment: i want to make a reusable function that should be used for unlimited no of operations instead of writing code again and again for every operation. that's why i need dynamic linq query approach.

Comment: Oh, I believe you are using the wrong approach. Use `IQueryable<T>` and chain instead of what you are doing, you are painting yourself into a corner.

Comment: Thanks actually i am playing with various approaches to check their performances, definitely direct linq approach is best

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to run a SQL string when using LINQ to entities. As other have pointed out, I'm not even sure if it is possible. The correct syntax would be something like:

```
var _list = new List<vsk_error_log>();
using (var entities = new vskdbEntities())
{
   _list = entities.vsk_error_log
  .Where(log => log.added_date >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1))
  .ToList();
}
return _list;
```

entity framework will then compile this into SQL for you

Comment: Your query is helpful, just need to extend it with linq dynamic expression instead of normal linq.

Answer (score 0):

Code posted below helped me fixed my issue.

```
var _list = new List<vsk_error_log>();
using (var entities = new vskdbEntities())
{
    _list = entities.vsk_error_log
         .Where("added_date >= @0", DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1))
         .OrderBy(entity.Order)
         .Skip(entity.PageSize * (entity.PageNumber - 1))
         .Take(entity.PageSize)
         .ToList();
 }
```

// Fetch data between two dates using dynamic linq

```
.Where("added_date >= @0 AND added_date < @1", DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7), DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: you can use the above method also with linq:

Answer (score 0):

// specify date range (without time)

```
   DateTime currentDate = System.DateTime.Now.Date;
   query = query.Where(p => p.added_date == currentDate);
```