# How to set DateTime equals method with Dynamic Linq in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, equals, dynamic-linq

I need to filter data with Dynamic LINQ by DateTime field.

I'm try doing this like:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private DateTime datetime_field;
    //...
    //some other fields
    //...
}

public void MyMethod(string where_clause)
{
    List<MyClass> myData = new List<MyClass>()
    {
        //...
        //initialization
        //...
    };
    var query = myData.Where(where_clause).ToList();
    myDataGridView.DataSource = query;
}

// usage
string value = DateTime.Now.ToString(); // for example
if (DateTime.TryParse(value, out DateTime dt))
    MyMethod("datetime_field == DateTime(" + dt.Year + ", " + dt.Month + ", " + dt.Day + ", " + dt.Hour + ", " + dt.Minute + ", " + dt.Second + ")");
```

But the query return zero records. But if i set compare method `>=` or `<=` instead `==`, query returns needed records amount.
Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

**UPDATE:**
I found example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26450835/7760805, but I'm still search a better solution.

**UPDATE:**
Solved by Stef Heyenrath.

Comment: DateTimes are precise way below the level of a second. Try throw away the milliseconds part of your datetime_field

Comment: @Flydog57, thanks, it's realy may help me. But how can I ignore milliseconds of my datetime_field with Dynamic LINQ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the accuracy you need, you could just use the `>=` and `<` operators together, like this:

```cs
var date = DateTime.Now;

// accuracy is 1 day in this example
var from = date.Date;
var to = from.AddDays(1);

// If you only need to select on a day, use this:
var result = query.Where("datetime_field >= @0 && datetime_field < @1", from, to);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I need!

Answer (score 3):

You should pass a string into the MyMethod method, then convert to DateTime and remove milliseconds within the method.

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    public DateTime datetime_field; // note this needs to be public, not private
}

public void MyMethod(string strDate)
{
    if (DateTime.TryParse(value, out DateTime dt))
    {
        List<MyClass> myData = new List<MyClass>()
        {
            // initialization
        };

        var roundedDate = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day,
                                       dt.Hour, dt.Minute, dt.Second);

        var query = myData.Where(obj => obj.date_time == roundedDate).ToList();

        myDataGridView.DataSource = query;   
    }
}

// usage
string value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
MyMethod(value);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this solution will crash all logic of my application. I need that parameter of `MyMethod` will be `string` type.

Comment: @VladiSlav Updated to match your logic.  

In my opinion, MyMethod should accept a DateTime object and chop milliseconds there.

Comment: I need to use Dynamic LINQ because I have several fields in MyClass, which besides DateTime can be string, int, etc. So `MyMethod` need to take **where clause** as string, not value for search.

Answer (score -1):

What is the content of MyMethod ?

Try using the $ string builder.

```
MyMethod($"datetime_field == {new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, dt.Hour, dt.Minute , dt.Second)}");
```

OR

```
MyMethod($"datetime_field == {dt.ToString())}");
```

I think its a problem with your logic not how you are constructing or passing datetime parameter.

Comment: Sorry, but this way calling an error: "Syntax error '{' ".

Comment: @VladiSlav hm. I think its a old version of C#

Comment: That is weird, You must be able to use $"".
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated