# Dynamic string in linq c#

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic-linq

I have installed `System.Linq.Dynamic` dll and then tried to add string as the parameter of WHERE clause in Linq. But I am still getting error that the string parameter is supported by WHERE clause.

Code:

```
_dbContext.TmRecords.Where("city=london");
```

Error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line Error  CS1503  Argument 2:
>   cannot convert from 'string' to
>   'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>'   Extranet.Domain

Here the city parameter dynamically changes to some other parameter. So, I need to use dynamic queries in linq.

Comment: You need to create a predicate, such as: `_dbContext.TmRecords.Where(record => record.city = "london");`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic WHERE clause in LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848415/dynamic-where-clause-in-linq)

Comment: @Mark it's about [dynamic Linq](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library), not regular Linq

Comment: My first guess in such cases would be that you forgot the correct `using`

Comment: Can you show the code for TmRecords?

Comment: Do you have `using System.Linq.Dynamic;` at the top of your file? Without that, the only method that the compiler can find is the one expecting an expression and not a string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should add `using System.Linq.Dynamic;` to your file.

Also rewrite the query like this:

```
_dbContext.TmRecords.Where("city = @0", "london");
```

Comment: using the `@0` is necessary or just good practice? Thanks, this helped me aswell :)

Comment: The same thing how can i use it in lamda expression?

Comment: It is not necessary. You can use `"City == \"london\""` instead but using parameterized one is more readable IMHO. @Roy_Dorsthorst

Comment: If you have another question then ask it in new question. @dineshsns