# How to filter a list with varying parameters in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose I have a class like this:

```
public class SampleClass
{
    public string SampleProperty1 { get; set; }
    public string SampleProperty2 { get; set; }
    public string SampleProperty3 { get; set; }
    public string SampleProperty4 { get; set; }
    public string SampleProperty5 { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a list like this:

```
List<SampleClass> sampleList = new List<SampleClass>();
```

I want to filter that list by `SampleProperty1` and `SampleProperty5`. Next time I will use `SampleProperty3` or `SampleProperty2`. I mean user can filter by any property he wants.

**How can I implement such flexibility?**

I don't want to write if statements as many as properties because the real number of properties is a lot more.

**Is there a smart way to do this?**

Thanks.

Comment: You need "generate" collection of predicates based on selected filters by user, then you can apply those predicates to your list. How you generate them, based on types of fields and types of filter (equality, contains, greater...)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic WHERE clause in LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848415/dynamic-where-clause-in-linq)

Comment: And a lot more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build lambda expression for each property and filter the collection with it.
Let's say you have `Dictionary` of property names with their values you want to filter by:

```
var filters = new Dictiontionary<string, object>();
IEnumerable<SampleClass> query = listOfSampleClasses;

// we will loop through the filters
foreach(filter in filters)
{
    // find the property of a given name
    var property = typeof(SampleClass).GetProperty(filter.Key, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
    if (property == null) continue;

    // create the ParameterExpression
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(SampleClass));
    // and use that expression to get the expression of a property
    // like: x.SampleProperty1
    var memberExpression = Expression.Property(parameter, property);

    // Convert object type to the actual type of the property
    var value = Convert.ChangeType(filter.Value, property.PropertyType, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    // Construct equal expression that compares MemberExpression for the property with converted value
    var eq = Expression.Equal(memberExpression, Expression.Constant(value));

    // Build lambda expresssion (x => x.SampleProperty == some-value)
    var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<SampleClass, bool>>(eq, parameter);

    // And finally use the expression to filter the collection
    query = query.Where(lambdaExpression);
}

var filteredList = query.ToList();
```

Of course, you can put that code inside a generic method and filter collection of any type.

For input dictionary, containing two pairs: `"SampleProperty1" - "foo"` and `"SampleProperty2" - "bar"`
It will produce something like that:

```
listOfSampleClasses
    .Where(x => x.SampleProperty1 == "foo")
    .Where(x => x.SampleProperty2 == "bar");
```

Comment: So for example, I have this string as a filter : `SampleProperty1=JasonANDSampleProperty2=Overflow` . How can I pass it to your `filters` dictionary.

Comment: First declare dictionary: `var filters = new Dictionary<string, object>();` And then add your values: `filters.Add("SampleProperty1", "Jason");` `filters.Add("SampleProperty2", "Overflow");`

Comment: Shouldn't `filters` be type of `<string, string>` then?

Comment: `object` is more flexible. Do you want to filter only by strings? What if there's an `int` property?

Comment: All properties are `string`. But yes `object` seems more logical. Thank you.

Comment: One last question : How can I implement `OR` in this approach? For example if I got this : `SampleProperty1=JasonANDSampleProperty2=Overflow`

Comment: Before building lambda expression you will have to build two Equal expressions and join them with `Expression.Or(eq1, eq2);`
You could store all Equal Expressions in some list and after all filters are processed build Or Expression based on the list and then create lambda expression and pass it to the `.Where()` method

Comment: Could `Convert.Change` be `Convert.ChangeType`?

Comment: Yes, it's `ChangeType`. Sorry, my bad.

Comment: And should I use `.Or` or `.OrElse` ? Thanks

Comment: It's really up to you. `Or` always evaluates both expressions, while `OrElse` skips the second one if the first is true, knowing that whole expression have to be true.

Comment: Someone told me that `Or` is `|` and `OrElse` is `||`

Comment: That's right. And it works perfectly fine with boolean values.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a LINQ statement with conditions like this.

```
var query = sampleList;

if(shouldFilterProperty1)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.SampleProperty1.Contains(SearchPattern1));
}
if(shouldFilterProperty2)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.SampleProperty2.Contains(SearchPattern2));
}

var result = query.ToList();
```

This is just an example for the first two properties. If you need other checks (not `Contains`) you can implement them in the same style.

Comment: This is just one way to do it. You can try writing it with reflection or more generic as well. The base would always be the same: 1. checking if you want to filter 2. Apply a new `Where` statement to your query.

Answer (score 1):

You could find the properties you want to filter through reflection and use this approach to build the LINQ query.

```
// create your sample list
List<SampleClass> sampleList = new List<SampleClass>();
sampleList.Add(...) 

// create the filter
Dictionary<string, string> Filter = new Dictionary<string, string>();
Filter.Add("SampleProperty1", "SearchPattern1");
Filter.Add("SampleProperty5", "SearchPattern5");

// create the linq query
var query = sampleList.AsEnumerable();    
foreach(var filterItem in Filter)
{   
    // get the property you want to filter
    var propertyInfo = typeof(SampleClass).GetProperty(filterItem.Key);

    // add the filter to your query
    query = query.Where(x => (string)propertyInfo.GetValue(x) == filterItem.Value);
}

// execute the query
var resultList = query.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the luxury of being able to change the structure of your  `SampleClass` class then you could try something like the following:

```
public class SampleClass
{
    public IDictionary<string, string> Properties { get; }
}

private static IList<SampleClass> FilterList(IList<SampleClass> list,
                                             params Tuple<string, string>[] propertyNames)
{
    // No point filtering here.
    if (propertyNames == null)
    {
        return list; // or null/empty list if you want to match none as the default.
    }

    // Match All the property values supplied in the filter, you can change this to
    // Contains or string.Equals, etc. to suit your matching needs.
    return list.Where(x => propertyNames.All(p => x.Properties[p.Item1] == p.Item2))
               .ToList();
}
```

Usage:

```
FilterList(sampleList,
           Tuple.Create("SampleProperty1", "Value1"),
           Tuple.Create("SampleProperty5", "Value5"));
```

The beauty of this approach means you don't need a large number of if statements in order to determine the  `Where` clause as originally asked for.