# Write a custom lambda expression that works on multiple entities in LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I have written a Lambda expression that perfectly works on a single entity (Customer):

```
var property = typeof(Customer).GetProperty(inputArray[0], BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Customer));
var memberExpression = Expression.Property(parameter, property);
var eq = Expression.Equal(memberExpression, Expression.Constant(value));
//Combining eq with ANDs and ORs
var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Customer, bool>>(eq, parameter);
var filteredCustomers = db.Customer.Where(lambdaExpression);
```

But I have more entities and I need to write a combined query that filters those entities as well. For example I have a `Product` entity and I want to filter products and customers at the same time. How can I change the above code so that it can work with multiple entities? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to filter `Customer` and `Product` at the same time or are you looking for a method that can filter both entities separately?

Comment: what "filter products and customers at the same time" means? Like multi thread "at the same time" or join "at the same time" :)

Comment: @ArkadiuszRaszeja join at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically principal is the same as I've posted in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43799398/7912895). The difference is that we will have to retrieve values of the nested properties. So we no longer need `PropertyValue` in the input dictionary, instead we would want to know what is the `Path` of that property. For example: `CustomerProducts.Customer.UserID`

Then we can split that path into the array of names of properties in each nesting level and build `MemberExpression` that's pointing from the root object (which is `CustomerProducts` in this case) to the deepest property by which we want to filter the collection. Here's the working example:

```
        // instead of passing pairs of PropertyName - PropertyValue
        // we'll pass pairs of PropertyPath - PropertyValue
        var filters = new Dictiontionary<string, object>();
        IEnumerable<CustomerProduct > query = listOfCustomerProducts;

        // we will loop through the filters
        foreach (var filter in filters)
        {
            // split property path by dot character
            var propertyNames = filter.Key.Split('.');

            PropertyInfo property = null;
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(CustomerProduct));

            MemberExpression memberExpression = null;

            // loop through all property names in path
            foreach (var t in propertyNames)
            {
                // get correct property type
                var type = property == null ? typeof(CustomerProduct) : property.PropertyType;
                // find property in the given type
                property = type.GetProperty(t, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
                if (property == null) break;

                // create member expression.
                memberExpression = memberExpression == null
                    // if there isn't one, create new, using parameter expression
                    ? Expression.Property(parameter, property)
                    // if there already is one, use it to get into the nested property
                    : Expression.Property(memberExpression, property);
            }

            if (property == null) continue;

            // Convert object type to the actual type of the property
            var value = Convert.ChangeType(filter.Value, property.PropertyType, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            // Construct equal expression that compares MemberExpression for the property with converted value
            var eq = Expression.Equal(memberExpression, Expression.Constant(value));

            // Build lambda expresssion (x => x.SampleProperty == some-value)
            var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<CustomerProduct, bool>>(eq, parameter);

            // And finally use the expression to filter the collection
            query = query.Where(lambdaExpression.Compile());
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what I was trying to say is to combine these two lambda expressions. For example a user can search like this : `(Select UserID = 5 and ProductName = "Banana")` or `(Select UserID = 5 and ProductName = "Banana" or UserName="Jason")`

Comment: So I assume that `UserID` is a property of `Customer`. And that `Customer` entity refers to `Product` entity in one to many relation, meaning `Customer` has a property `ICollection<Product>` or something like that. And `Product` entity has a `ProductName` property. Is that correct?

Comment: Actually there is no relation with tables. But `Customer` has `UserID` and `Product` has `ProductName` (there are a lot more properties in these entities).  As I said there is no relation between these tables but I need to do searches as I said in the above comment.

Comment: So how do you want to join these tables if there's no relation between them?

Comment: I also have `CustomerProduct` table. So I join them using it. Sorry I forgot to mention that.

Comment: Is your approach applicable to this situation?

Comment: You can create `MemberExpression` of a nested property:
`var propertyInfo = typeof(CustomerProduct).GetProperty("Customer");`
`var nestedProperty = propertyInfo.PropertyType.GetProperty("UserID");`
`var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(CustomerProduct));`
`var member = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyInfo);`
`var nestedMember = Expression.Property(member, nestedProperty);`

then the `nestedMember` will point to `CustomerProduct.Customer.UserId`

Comment: It will be generic version of your answer to this question : http://stackoverflow.com/a/43799398/1954132